# Different symbols around parameters of a function in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

If I define a function as `\SetKwFunction{Func}{func}` in algorithm2e, `\Func{a, b}` prints

> func(a, b)

by default. How can I make it print

> func[a, b]

like in Wolfram or

> func a b

like in Haskell?

I looked into the documentation of algorithm2e and didn't find anything for that, but the inability to change this seems like a strange limitation with all the customisation available in algorithm2e. If it isn't possible, what are some easy alternatives to `\SetKwFunction` with similar behavior and with that ability?

## Example

The preamble of the document is this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}
\SetFuncSty{textsf}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{function}{}{}
```

The first case is produced by the following code and other cases show how it is supposed to look but are produced with workarounds.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwFunction{Factorial}{factorial}

    \Fn{\Factorial{x}}{
        \uIf{\(x \le 1\)}{
            0
        }\Else{
            \(x \cdot \Factorial{\(x-1\)}\)
    } }
\end{algorithm}

This here \Factorial{x} grows very rapidly with \(x\).
```

[image: examples of how it looks and how it could look]

The `factorial x - 1` in the last case should have parentheses but I noticed the mistake too late and decided to keep it for the sake of demonstration.

Comment: Can you please add a small example of code to play with? Starting from scratch and guessing what you have is painful.

Comment: @egreg I added an example of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest some surgery on the package. The opening and closing parentheses are hardwired, so we replace them with macros. Also a separate style is assigned to the delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwFunction}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname##1{%
    \FuncSty{#2}\FuncDelSty{\FuncOpen}\FuncArgSty{##1}\FuncDelSty{\FuncClose}%
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname @#1\endcsname}{\FuncSty{#2}\xspace}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\FuncDelSty}[1]{\textnormal{#1}\unskip}
\newcommand{\SetFuncDelSty}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\FuncDelSty}[1]{\textnormal{\csname#1\endcsname{##1}}\unskip}%
}
\providecommand{\gobblearg}[1]{}
\newcommand{\FuncOpen}{(}
\newcommand{\FuncClose}{)}
\newcommand{\matharg}[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\SetFuncArgSty{matharg} % function arguments are in math, not in text
\makeatother

\SetFuncSty{textsf}
\SetKwProg{Fn}{function}{}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\haskellargs}{m}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \ensuremath{\;\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \; }}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\section*{Standard}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwFunction{Factorial}{factorial}
    \Fn{\Factorial{x}}{
        \uIf{\(x \le 1\)}{
            0
        }\Else{
            \(x \cdot \Factorial{x-1}\)
    } }
\end{algorithm}

\section*{Brackets}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwFunction{Factorial}{factorial}
    \renewcommand{\FuncOpen}{[}\renewcommand{\FuncClose}{]}
    \Fn{\Factorial{x}}{
        \uIf{\(x \le 1\)}{
            0
        }\Else{
            \(x \cdot \Factorial{x-1}\)
    } }
\end{algorithm}

\section*{Haskell}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwFunction{Factorial}{factorial}
    \SetFuncArgSty{haskellargs}
    \renewcommand{\FuncOpen}{}\renewcommand{\FuncClose}{}
    \Fn{\Factorial{x}}{
        \uIf{\(x \le 1\)}{
            0
        }\Else{
            \(x \cdot \Factorial{(x-1)}\)
    } }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \SetKwFunction{Test}{test}
    \SetFuncArgSty{haskellargs}
    \renewcommand{\FuncOpen}{}\renewcommand{\FuncClose}{}
    \Fn{\Test{x,y}}{
        \uIf{\(x>y\)}{
          $x-y$
        }\Else{
          $y-x$
    } }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Of course you will choose the style once and for all.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may be achieved by changing `SetKwFunction` implementation as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwFunction}[2]{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname @#1\endcsname##1{\FuncSty{#2[}\FuncArgSty{##1}\FuncSty{]}}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname#1\endcsname{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\csname @#1\endcsname}{\FuncSty{#2}\xspace}}%
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \SetKwFunction{Func}{func}
  \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{:}{\KwRet}
  \Fn{\Func{$f$, $a$, $b$, $\varepsilon$}}{
        a\;
        b\;
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]